# Use URL on Android throws IOException: Malformed ipv6 address

Tags: java, android

I want to send the data on the android emulator to the local host web, and get some results.

```
String temp = "http://10.0.2.2:8888/json/rec?user_data=" + user_data + "&friends=" + friends;
URL url = new URL(temp);

HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
urlConnection.setReadTimeout(5000);
InputStreamReader is = new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream(), "UTF-8");
String output = "";
while(is.ready()) {
    output += is.read();
}
```

Here is the exception.

```
java.io.IOException: Malformed ipv6 address: [10.0.2.2:8888]
```

Why it said that?
Could someone help me?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its a known bug thats fixed in a future release.

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=12724

The easy fix is to use a different constructor to the URL .. the one that accepts hostname, port and file

```
URL(String protocol, String host, int port, String file)
```

EDIT

In your case, it would be

```
URL url = new URL("http", "10.0.2.2" , 8888 , "json/rec?user_data=" + user_data + "&friends=" + friends);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks. I have read URL at JAVA document. And I hava some questions is that when I set the URL this way, so: protocol = http, host = 10.0.2.2, port = 8888, then file = ?

Answer (score 0):

Probably because the host contains a colon, which it takes to mean this is a numeric IPv6 address