# How to send JSON from android to Servlet

Tags: java, android, json

I  get the JSON of User Info from Facebook on Android.
And then send the JSON to my servlet (the platform is GAE).

My question is how to send it properly.
Since the JSON could be very long.
So far, I have tried [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6811482/use-url-on-android-throws-ioexception-malformed-ipv6-address).
But I cannot receive the entire JSON.
It always throws

> Unterminated string at character 117 of
>   {"music":{"data":[{"created_time":"2011-05-23T16:47:21
>   0000","id":"176345129540","category":"Musician/band","name":"

And I print the JSON, I find that the JSON is just as above which is been cut.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean the JSON of User Info from Facebook? I use Facebook Android SDK. http://developers.facebook.com/docs/sdks/

Answer (score 0):

There might be a limit on the size of data you can send by Http GET, take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2253061/secure-http-post-in-android) and rewrite your request to use Http POST.